# React Native - react-native-highcharts only showing when remote JS debugging enabled

Tags: android, highcharts, react-native

I'm using the library [react-native-highcharts](https://github.com/TradingPal/react-native-highcharts), the charts are showing correctly on an android emulator running 6.0 only when remote JS debugging is enabled. Without debugging enabled nothing shows up. The charts also do not show when the apk is installed on a physical android 6.0 device

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-native": "0.40.0",
    "react-native-highcharts": "^0.1.1"
```

Does anyone know why this might be or how find out what the problem is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this issue already locate in `react-native-highcharts` for physical devices

[view issue](https://github.com/TradingPal/react-native-highcharts/issues/4)